# Blocking all sites/IP address but Google.se with iptables

Tags: ip, iptables, blocking

Im trying to block all IPs but Google.se. It doesnt work (Site does not display)

Here is what I wrote:

```
#/bin/sh
echo "Flushing IPTables..."
sleep 1
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
echo "Done!"

echo "Setting Firewall..."
sleep 1
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m iprange --src-range 0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m iprange --src-range 0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255 -j DROP

iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -d www.google.se -p tcp --dport 80 --sport 1024:65355   -j ACCEPT
echo "Done!"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I can see a few problems with your firewall, mostly you appear to be dropping things on input and output but ignoring forwarding.  Thus everything on the local machine will be blocked but nothing on the machines behind the firewall.

You were unclear if you are wanting to block traffic entering/leaving the device on which the firewall rules are running or if you are wanting to block thing behind the firewall.  Similarly you have not advised if you want to block incoming or outgoing traffic (either will have the same apparent affect when web browsing, but different security implications)

If you are wanting to block things being forwarded (as implied from the last line of the script), and you are not worried about access from the actual box doing the firewalling (and the defaults are set to ACCEPT as per your example):

```
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -i wlan0 -d www.google.se -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Should work, provided that the clients are using a local DNS server and able to resolve www.google.se - AND IMPORTANTLY (but probably an invalid assumption), The nameserver always resolves www.google.se to the same IP address.

The first line says "If the traffic is passing through this box and I don't know about it, don't allow the traffic through".
The second line, which is inserted (so read before the line above) says allow outbound requests to www.google.se
The third line says "If we successfully made a connection to the IP, we can allow it to talk to us".